# AngularJS controller stuck in loop for IE11.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

My site works fine for Chrome, Safari and Firefox. However when I run it on IE11 I'm getting strange behaviour. The homepage loads fine but when I try to navigate to another page a controller is executing in an infinite loop.

Here's some code:

```
$scope.page = Page;

//set page title
if ($routeParams.type == "television"){
  console.log('setting television title & meta'); //keeps printing this
  Page.setMeta('some meta');
  Page.setTitle('some title');
  if ($routeParams.brand != undefined){
    Page.setTitle($routeParams.brand + 'some title');
  }
  console.log('complete'); //keeps printing this
}
```

Eventually I get a message 'site not responding due to a long running script'.

There is no redirect code at any point...

Can anyone offer any insight here??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? Where is the markup that refers to this controller? Where have you defined your routes?

Comment: If you're trying to open a new tab, open the console, and then make the same steps again, are there any console errors?

Comment: If you remove everything from inside that if statement except for the console.log what happens?

Comment: I've investigated further. I still get the problem if I remove everything apart from the console.log. Can't open a new tab as IE hangs. No errors. When I look at the heroku logs I can see the GET request for the data returns 200 when using chrome, firefox etc but when using IE it returns 304 - "If the client has done a conditional GET and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified since the date and time specified in If-Modified-Since field, the server responds with a 304 status code and does not send the document body to the client." Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Using Fiddler or another tool that shows what's hitting the network, what are the request `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` headers? IE follows RFC2616 caching rules for XmlHttpRequest-sent requests. Chrome and Firefox are less likely to use cached content if request URL has a `?` in it.

Comment: I'm getting an error 10 digest iterations reached. I think this is because I am loading the title and meta desc based on the route and when this changes it forces a new render hence the looping. Seems like  IE can't handle this but other browsers could. Thanks for the help.